# how to connect a client to multiple servers which are held in threads in c

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select

i successfully connected a client to one server which handles I/O through select function,then i created more servers with threads.In client i created new sockets , i made connection to those servers in different port numbers successfully and sent the first message from a server to client and client to server respectively.Although select in those servers can handle new connections , it is not recognizing I/O from existing connected sockets.

client:

```
bzero(buffer,1024);
valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);//receive first message
printf("%s\n",buffer );
while (1) {
  bzero(buffer,1024);
  printf("write:\n");
  fgets(buffer,1024,stdin);//write something
  buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
  if (strcmp(buffer,"exit***")==0) {
     valread = write(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer));
     exit(1);
  }
  send(sock , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );//here program stuck and waiting for select in server, but in server nothing happens
  bzero(buffer,1024);
  valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
  printf("%s\n",buffer );
}
```

in a situation with a single server and many clients,it works but in a multi server situation(in threads) like this, it stuck in the select function.Is there any bug with threads and select?

**update**

i found that the error is in fgets(buffer,1024,stdin);
In the first iteration ,fgets is not waiting for user to type something and 
it passes 0 bytes to send function...The server cannot handle this.

**solution**
before that code i added while ((getchar()) != '\n'); to clear the buffer which probably had a new line inside and caused that behaviour

Comment: You ought to show your server code, too.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths updated post